# Removing file from Mercurial MQ Patch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have large MQ patch applied in Mercurial. What has happened is I have done qrefresh and included files in my patch that I do not want to include. Is there a way to remove the changes to these file from my patch with out manually editing it? In this case if I was just working without MQ, all I would have to do is hg revert.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With the patch applied:

```
hg qrefresh -X [file1] -X [file2] ... -X [fileN]
```

Will take out file1 to fileN of the patch. After completing that, type `hg status` to verify that the files are now marked as modified, and therefore not part of the patch any longer .

Comment: The `-X` switch has to come before each file name. So to remove foo and bar, use `hg qrefresh -X foo -X bar`.

Comment: If you want to remove all files from the patch, instead of remove each file, you could run `hg qrefresh -X '*'`. You must surround the `*` character with `'` to prevent the shell to interpret before the mercurial.

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work in 4.8 for Windows. I used `-X` and `--exclude`, using full filename and glob, in quotes and without them, nothing works.  `hg qdiff --stat` returns file list unchanged

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use make the patch the current patch (applied and at the top of the stack) and then `hg forget` and `hg qrefresh`.

And of course `hg forget` is just `hg remove` without requiring extra options to avoid file deletion.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to do `hg qrefresh` with all the files except the one you want to remove - that'll take the changes out of the patch without discarding them.